# Given a web response, how do I extract a specific portion for further processing?

Tags: c#, html, .net-4.0, html-parsing

I have some code that gets a web response. How do I take that response and search for a table using its CSS class (class="data")? Once I have the table, I need to extract certain field values. For example, in the sample markup below, I need the values of Field #3 and Field #5, so "85" and "1", respectively.

```html
<table width="570" border="0" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="2" class="data">
  <tr>
    <td width="158"><strong>Field #1:</strong></td>
    <td  width="99">1</td>
    <td  width="119"><strong>Field #2:</strong></td>
    <td  width="176">110</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="158"><strong>Field #3:</strong></td>
    <td  width="99">85</td>
    <td  width="119"><strong>Field #4:</strong></td>
    <td  width="176">-259.34</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="158"><strong>Field #5:</strong></td>
    <td  width="99">1</td>
    <td  width="119"><strong>Field #6:</strong></td>
    <td  width="176">110</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="158"><strong>Field #7:</strong></td>
    <td  width="99">12</td>
    <td  width="119"><strong>Field #8:</strong></td>
    <td  width="176">123.23</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Look in the "Related" links list on the right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [HTML Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) and [parse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parsing) the HTML. If you want to do it the simplest way then go grab its beta ([it supports LINQ](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Examples)).

Comment: You could also parse this as XML if you are 100% sure that it will be XML-compliant, but most HTML pages are not (even the xhtml ones).

Answer (score 0):

As Randolf suggests, using HTML Agility Pack is a good option.

But, if you have control of the format of the HTML, it is also possible to do string parsing to extract the values you are after.

It is nearly trivial to download the entire HTML as a string and search for the string "`<table`" followed by the string "class=\"data\"". Then you can easily extract the values you are after by doing similar string manipulations.

I'm not saying you should do this, for the resulting code will be harder to read and maintain that the code using HTML Agility Pack, but it will save you an external dependency and your code will probably perform much better.

In a WP7 app I made, I started using HTML Agility Pack to parse some HTML and extract some values. This worked well, but it was quite slow. Switching to the string parsing regime made my code many times faster while returning the exact same result.

Comment: How would you parse the string? Regular expressions?

Comment: That depends. Regexes are nice, but hard to read. Extracting substrings is easier but can be tricky to maintain. The latter is the option I ended up using in my WP7 app. It works well, but I need many unit tests to ensure that I don't break anything.

Comment: Regexes pretty much only work on regular languages. HTML is not a regular language.

Comment: Agreed. But as long as you know the exact format of the HTML you are parsing you can still get an acceptable solution.